# Pow function vs lookup texture in shader

Tags: shader, hlsl, lookup-tables, xbox360

I'm developing for the XBOX 360, and I use the pow() intrinsic in some lighting calculations.

6-8 years ago it [used to be common](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/2972/a_noninteger_power_function_on_.php?page=1) to use a 1D lookup texture to approximate pow(). Does anyone still do that?

Is it worth trying this for the 6 year old XBOX 360, or is it unlikely to improve performance?

Comment: Are you actually pixel-shader limited anyway? Removing individual instructions is very much a micro-optimisation. Even if you are pixel-shader limited you can probably find better place to improve performance.

Comment: I'm trying to fit another point light or two into the scene, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the [`pow` instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147285(v=VS.85).aspx) (or the equivalent [intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509636(v=VS.85).aspx) function in HLSL).** It takes 3 instruction slots, which indicates that it is reasonably quick.

I haven't sat down and figured out the exact cost of doing a lookup table. But you would struggle to find a useful implementation in fewer instruction slots. And obviously it requires a texture read (which is itself not free, and there's a good chance it will be a dependent texture read and so quite slow).

(Additionally: if a lookup texture were a better choice, then the GPU could just implement the `pow` instruction like that itself.)

The reason that it used to be common to use a texture is that the `pow` instruction did not exist for either [vertex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172935(v=VS.85).aspx) or [pixel shaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219851(v=VS.85).aspx) in shader model 1.x. In 2.x and everything newer it is available ([more instruction sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219840(v=VS.85).aspx)).

Comment: I don't know anything about the 360's GPU, but lookup textures are [still relevant](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=2001+all+voer+again+aras&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Faras-p.info%2Fblog%2F2011%2F02%2F01%2Fios-shader-tricks-or-its-2001-all-over-).